# Don't know how to refer to a file in my project using ms-appx (wp8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to refer to a grammar file in my project(Rootfile->folder named grammar->the file named NumbersGrammar) I used this line of code but it tells me the 0x80070002 error (the system cannot find the file specified):

`Uri Numbers = new Uri("ms-appx:///Grammar/NumbersGrammar.grxml" ,UriKind.Absolute);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the file exists in the specified location, and it's `Build Action` property is set to `Content`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `appdata` instead? In your case the full path would be

```
new Uri("appdata:/Grammar/NumbersGrammar.grxml");
```

Apparently although `appdata` and `ms-appx` both refer to the installation folder, they must be used for different situations.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Installationfolder