# Accepting self signed Certificates? (Windows Universal App)

Tags: webview, certificate, self-signed, win-universal-app

How do I enable the Webview control to accept self signed certificate for a Windows Universal App? I am migrating an existing app from Windows 8.1 to Windows Universal. During this process I am unable to include the self signed certificate as part of the deployment package anymore. I have attempted the following steps:

1. Copied the mycert.cer file to the Solutions Explorer.
2. Verified that MyDocuments->Visual Studio 2015->MyApp contains the mycert.cer file.
3. Appended the following code snipped into the package.appxmanifest file

> ```
> Extensions
>   Extension Category="windows.Certificates"
>     Certificates
>         Certificate StoreName="Root" Content="mycert.cer"
>     Certificates
>   Extension
> Extensions
> ```

The problem is that no matter how I add mycert.cer to my project I cant seem to get past the deployment phase. I continuously receive the following error:

> Error   Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. C:Path to my
>   project: error 0x80070002: Cannot register
>   bc88a047-f619-4de8-8903-45c6c485ae92_1.0.0.0_neutral__v48a8278bjx14
>   package because the following error was encountered while trying to
>   open and evaluate the mycert.cer certificate to add to the Root store:
>   The system cannot find the file specified. (0x80073cf6) MyAppName

What am I doing wrong here? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after I asked the question I stumbled upon the following post https://stackoverflow.com/a/18843580/680778. If you are experiencing this issue please ensure that for the build action in the Solution Explorer you have selected Content for the mycert.cer file. The above post saved me a headache. When a newly added file is added to a project the default Build Action is set to none thus, the file will not be copied to the build location.